# For If Statement

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm having an issue with my For If statement. The scenario is that, I need the empty cells to be filled with a telephone number. I have made a code and it works but at some point it will stop in between. Sometimes all the way to the end of the last row or just skip a few cells and continue again. I'm really not sure about this weird issue, hopefully someone can give me an insight. I have also attached a snapshot of the results.

My code is as shown below:-

```
    Dim pn As Range
    Dim h As Integer, phone As Integer
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set pn = Range("AE2:AE" & lastrow)
    h = 1

    For phone = 1 To pn.Rows.Count
       If pn.Cells(h) = "" Then
         pn.Cells(h) = "03-33422828"
       Else
         h = h + 1
       End If
    Next
```

[image]

Comment: Get rid of all the `h` lines and use `pn.Cells(phone)`.

Comment: Gosh! All this time my understanding on the For If statement implementation has been a bit wrong.. Thanks a lot BigBen! It worked accordingly :D

Comment: Even better, `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in pn`, `If cell.Value = "" Then`, `cell.Value = "03-33422828"`, `End If`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way to do this is to select all the used cells in that range, then fill all the blank ones with a value.

For example, if we have a workbook with data in column A and we want to fill the blank cells in that column with "---" we could do this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count). _
  SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "---"
On Error GoTo 0
```

VBA will generate an error if there are no blank cells, so I've "handled" that by just ignoring any errors.

[image: Before & After]

For you it would be more like:

```
On Error Resume Next
Range("AE1:AE" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count). _
  SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "03-33422828"
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Hey there Robson. This is actually a good alternative way, shorter way too! I've tried it and will also definitely implement this method in future. Thank you very much mate! :D